# ASP.NET MVC URL Routing with parameters in the middle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller called Quote, with an Index method that requires a requestId parameter. The URL appears as such

```
/Quote/{requestId}.
```

Additionally, I have a method called ApplicantInfo which is specific to the quote and routes as such

```
/Quote/{requestId}/ApplicantInfo.
```

But when I use the Url.Action helper like so

```
@Url.Action("Index","Quote",new { requestId = {requestId}})
```

It gives me a url of

```
/Quote/ApplicantInfo?requestId={requestId}
```

which does not route correctly.

Obviously, I can manually create the URL string, but before I throw in the towel I wanted to know if I was missing something, for instance an override to the `Url.Action` method that will output the correct `Url`.

TIA

*ROUTES*

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "QuoteInfo",
            "Quote/{requestid}", 
            new { controller = "Quote", action="Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
            "QuoteApplicant",
            "Quote/{requestid}/ApplicantInfo", 
            new { controller = "Quote", action = "ApplicantInfo" });

routes.MapRoute(
             "Default",
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
     new { controller = "Home", action="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: can you show me your RegisterRoutes method in RouteConfig if you do all your routings here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get do something similar to this like this

### Route

Define a route in `Global.asax.cs` or whereeve you override your routes

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Organization_default",
            "{controller}/{requestId}/{action}", 
            new { 
                  controller = "home", 
                  action = "index", 
                  requestId = "default",
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional 
             }, null);
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult Question(string requestId)
    {
        ViewData["value"] = requestId;
        return View();
    }
```

### View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var value = ViewData["value"];
}

<h2>Stackoverflow @value</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here", 
        "question", "StackOverflow", new { requestId ="Link" }, new{   @id="link"})
```

### Screenshot

screenshot of how the links appear with this route, I defined the 
[image]

### Catch

You **CANNOT** have another route as `{controller}/{action}/{key}` defined before your custom this route. If you do the other route override your custom route.

If you need both the routes to co-exist then you would have to define a separate **Area** and define your custom route overriding `RegisterArea`

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   //..custom route definition
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me where I needed to be.